# Why python does not behave the same when printing unicode strings in console and pipes?

Tags: python, encoding, stdout

After a couple tests, I managed to restrict a misfunctionning in the minimal test.py script below:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
print u"Vérifier l'affichage de cette chaîne"
```

Note: test.py is encoded in ISO-8859-1 (ie latin-1), ie "é" equals "\xe9" and "î" equals "\xee"

```
D:\test>python --version
Python 2.7.3
D:\test>python test.py
Vérifier l'affichage de cette chaîne
D:\test>python test.py > test.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    print u"VÚrifier l'affichage de cette cha¯ne"
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is the question :

How come python does not behave the same when printing unicode strings whether its standard output goes to the console or is redirected or piped to something else?

Comment: Actually, it's the same behaviour on Linux (Ubuntu)

Comment: If you want to print Latin-1, you can explicitly `print s.encode('ISO-8859-1')`. But your console is probably not set for Latin-1, but for Windows-1252, so this will do the wrong thing.

Comment: Hold on… `ISO-8859-1` isn't a valid coding system. In the `encode` function it's a valid synonym for `iso-8859-1`, but I get errors from emacs when I try to save a file that way (and the file gets saved as UTF-8), and it also looks like Python ignores the coding.

Comment: @abarnet: yes that's the way I fixed my script eventually, but the question remains : why does it work when the standard output directly goes to the console, whereas an exception is raised when the output is piped?

Comment: @abarnet: 'import codecs; codecs.lookup("ISO-8859-1")' works, thus I guess ISO-8859-1 is a valid coding system for python, isn't it?

Comment: @aroyer: No, that just means that codec lookup (a) does case-insensitive comparisons, and (b) handles a whole slew of synonyms even beyond the ones that are documented.

Comment: OK, I've changed the encoding statement in lower case so that we focus on the question.

Comment: As my answer already explains, the (second) issue has nothing to do with your coding. Take the coding line out, and write an ASCII file that prints the same string by using `\u` escapes, and you'll see the exact same thing.

Answer (score 4):

First, `ISO-8859-1` isn't a valid coding declaration. You want `iso-8859-1`. If you look at [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html), you can call this `latin_1`, `iso-8859-1`, `iso8859-1`, `8859`, `cp819`, `latin`, `latin1`, or `L1`, but not `ISO-8859-1`.

It looks like `codecs.lookup` bends over backward to accept bad input, including doing case-insensitive lookups. If you trace [`codecs.lookup`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/codecs.py) through [`_codecs.lookup`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/_codecsmodule.c) to [`_PyCodec_Lookup`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/codecs.c), you can see this comment:

```
/* Convert the encoding to a normalized Python string: all
   characters are converted to lower case, spaces and hyphens are
   replaced with underscores. */
```

But source file decoding doesn't go through the same codec lookup process. Because it happens at compile time rather than runtime, there's no reason for it to do so. (At any rate, saying "It seems to work, even though the docs say it's wrong… so why doesn't it quite work right?" is kind of silly in the first place.)

To demonstrate, if I create two Latin-1 files:

badcode.py:

```
# -*- coding: ISO-8859-1 -*-
print u"Vérifier l'affichage de cette chaîne"
```

goodcode.py:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
print u"Vérifier l'affichage de cette chaîne"
```

The first one fails, the second succeeds.

Now, why does it "work" when it's going to console but raise an exception when piped?

Well, when you print to a Windows console, or a Unix TTY, Python has some code to try to guess the right encoding to use. (I'm not sure what happens under the covers on Windows; it might even be using UTF-16 output, for all I know.) When you're not printing to a console/TTY, it can't do this, so you have to specify the encoding explicitly.

You can see some of what's going on by looking at `sys.stdout.isatty()`, `sys.stdout.encoding`, and `sys.getdefaultencoding()`. Here's what I see on a Mac in different cases:

- Python 2, no redirect: `True, UTF-8, ascii, Vérifier`
- Python 3, no redirect: `True, UTF-8, utf-8, Vérifier`
- Python 2, redirect: `False, None, ascii, UnicodeEncodeError`
- Python 3, redirect: `False, UTF-8, utf-8, Vérifier`

If `isatty()`, `encoding` will be an appropriate encoding for the TTY; otherwise, `encoding` will be the default value, which is `None` (meaning `ascii`) in 2.x, and (I think—I'd have to check the code) something based on `getdefaultencoding()` in 3.x. Which means that if you try to print Unicode while `stdout` is not a TTY in 2.x, it will try to encode it as `ascii`, `strict`, which will fail if you've got non-ASCII characters.

If you somehow know what codec you want to use, you can deal with this manually by checking `isatty()` and encoding to that codec (or even to `ascii`, `ignore` instead of `strict`, if you prefer) whenever you print, instead of trying to print Unicode. (If you know what codec you want, you may want to do this even in 3.x—defaulting to UTF-8 isn't too helpful if you're trying to generate, say, Windows-1252 files…)

The difference there actually has nothing to do with Latin-1. Try this out:

nocode.py:

```
print u"V\xe9rifier l'affichage de cette cha\xeene"
print u"V\u00e9rifier l'affichage de cette cha\u00eene"
```

I get the Unicode strings encoded to UTF-8 for my Mac terminal, and (apparently) Windows-1252 to my Windows cmd window, but an exception redirecting to a file.

Comment: Anyone know why SO is refusing to accept the last line of code as code, no matter what I try to do with blank lines, comment lines, etc. around it?

Comment: No idea. I replaced the 4 spaces in the front with 4 spaces and it seems to be working now.

Comment: @gnibbler: Thanks! Obviously 4 spaces are better than 4 spaces. :)

Comment: They need to be #32. I bet they were #160. I've seen that before. No idea where the #160's come from mind you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I clicked the `{}` icon instead of manually adding spaces as I usually do for 1-liners. Which you'd think would be _more_ likely to work, rather than less, but then we all write software for a living, so we know better. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since I came here looking for the "don't be smart" switch to python's print() and the answer provides hints to read-only variables, here's the "make python believe stdout can handle utf-8" snippet:

```
import sys, codecs

# somewhere in the function you need it or global main():
sys.stdout = codecs.open('/dev/stdout', encoding='utf-8', mode='w', errors='strict')
```

There, now python doesn't care if it's a tty, tee(1), file redirection or just cat(1) for the heck of it.